# How to interconnect different inputs in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `dataset` with 2 columns: `p` and `r`, that I will use later to filter the information on a plot based on user input. The user will either enter the value (`input$pnum` and `input$rat`) or chooses it on a slider (`input$pval` and `input$ratio`).

1. If a numeric input is entered, the slider needs to get updated automatically, and vice-versa, if the user choses a value on the slider, the numeric input gets also updated.
2. Min and max values of the slider are defined based on the data using `dataset$p` to define min/max of `input$pval` and `dataset$r` to define starting values of `input$ratio`.

Until this point the code is giving me the desired output. However I would like to include an **additional condition**: when the value of `input$ratio` is changed min and max values of `input$pval` should be recalculated using the subset of the data where `r>=input$ratio`, and in the same way, when `input$pval` is changed by user min/max values on the slider for `input$ratio` should be recalculated.

Adding these conditions returns the following warnings and `NaN`'s are displayed on the slider instead of actual values.

> ```
> > Warning in max(dataset$r[which(-log10(as.numeric(dataset$p)) >=
> > input$pnum)],  :   no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> > Warning in
> > max(abs(log10(as.numeric(dataset$p[which(as.numeric(dataset$r) >=  :  
> > no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf Warning in
> > max(dataset$r[which(-log10(as.numeric(dataset$p)) >= input$pnum)],  : 
> > no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf Warning in
> > max(abs(log10(as.numeric(dataset$p[which(as.numeric(dataset$r) >=  :  
> > no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> ```

The code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Plot result", tabName = "scatterplot", icon = icon("area-chart"))
))

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "scatterplot", 
            fluidRow(
              box(
                uiOutput("rat"),
                uiOutput("ratio"),
                uiOutput("pnum"),
                uiOutput("pval"),
                width = 5
              )
            )
    )
  )
)


ui=dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "analysis"),
  sidebar,
  body
)


server=shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  dataset <- structure(list(p = c(6.03934743495282e-02, 1.50433174696588e-01, 
                                  2.08047037184403e-03, 5.89297106629446e-05, 0.000102485231497565, 
                                  0.0010651774924444, 0.0126458836222225, 0.000210364148948929, 
                                  0.00274720409905674, 0.281095738489031, 0.000316170681574214, 
                                  0.0316321461125659, 0.000369171267912158, 0.000369171267912158, 
                                  0.0395213746526263, 0.475174078010843, 0.000718770258398781, 
                                  0.760859052164441, 0.000810153915789446, 0.000875314011490406
  ), ratio_p_group_min = c(1.57380553778931, 1.11245772000324, 
                           1.504084996599, 1.00963266560562, 1.28098052443163, 1.49882201127675, 
                           1.10761702001084, 0.767267328293303, 1.03412495601202, 1.33508933929913, 
                           0.835478202626155, 0.998537147454481, 1.2008830437325, 1.2008830437325, 
                           1.15710746065582, 0.99677375722945, 1.37744067975694, 1.3666109673056, 
                           1.34583027836758, 1.34766012381264)), .Names = c("p", "r"
                           ), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")


  output$rat <- renderUI({
        numericInput("rat","Define minumun ratio", value = input$ratio,step=0.01 , width = '40%')
  })   

  output$ratio <- renderUI({
    dataset <- dataset[which(!is.na(dataset$r)),]   
    #***this is the first line causing error
    maxkaw <- round(max(dataset$r[which(-log10(as.numeric(dataset$p))>=input$pnum)],na.rm=T),digits=2) 
    minkaw <- round(min(dataset$r,na.rm=T),digits=2)
    sliderInput("ratio",NULL, min   = minkaw, 
                max   = maxkaw,
                value = input$rat)
  })

  output$pnum <- renderUI({
    numericInput("pnum","-log10(P)", value = input$pval,step=0.001, width = '40%')
  })

  output$pval <- renderUI({
    dataset <- dataset[which(!is.na(dataset$r)),]
    #***this is the second line causing error
    maxpval <- round(max(abs(log10(as.numeric(dataset$p[which(as.numeric(dataset$r)>=input$rat)]))),na.rm=T),digits=2) 
    sliderInput("pval",NULL, min   = 0, 
                max   = maxpval,
                value = input$pnum)
  }) 
})


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: This is because your `max(-log10(as.numeric(dataset$p)))` is equal to ` 4.229666` which is less that max value of your `input$pval` which is `4.23`. Hence when the value of your`input$pval` exceeds `4.229666` your statement`round(max(dataset$r[which(-log10(as.numeric(dataset$p))>=input$pnum)],na.rm=T),digits=2) ` return `integer(0)` causing that error.

Comment: That's a very good point, thank you! However the problem is still didsn't solved. After further examination it seems to me that is the initial values of `input$ratio` and `input$pval` that are causing the trouble. I believe for a few seconds these two variables doesn't have any values assigned, thus throwing the Warning, but I have no idea how to overcome this problem

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the case. When you do `round(max(dataset$r[which(-log10(as.numeric(dataset‌​$p))>=input$pnum)],n‌​a.rm=T),digits=2)` the first time `input$pval` is `NULL` which is giving you the warning. You could place a condition to check that the `inputs` are not `NULL ` before executing the code.

Comment: Thank you, that worked !